# HTML/CSS Designing a responsive website. An onclick attribute won't function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive design for a practice website.
The situation is that the below menu-icon image is only displayed while width is less than 701 px. So it does that fine. But the problem is that, when menu-icon image is displayed, screen width less than 701 px, I click on the image and nothing happens. The onclick attribute "togglemenu()" does not seem to function. Can someone help please?
This is a live site:

https://moortje.github.io/HTML-CSS-Project-Bro-Code/

The menuList and menu-icon in question are at the very bottom.

Here is an HTML snippet.

```
<ul id="menuList">
    <li><a href="">CSI</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="">HCSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="">JS</a></li>
</ul>
       
<img src="moortje2.png" class="menu-icon" onclick="togglemenu()">
    
<script type="text/javascript">
        
    var menuList = document.getElementById("menuList");
       
    menuList.style.maxHeight = "0px";
      
    function togglemenu(){
        
        if (menuList.style.maxHeight == "0px") {
            menuList.style.maxHeight = "130px";
        }

        else{
            menuList.style.maxHeight = "0px";
            }
    }
        
</script>
```

Here is a CSS snippet.

```
.menu-icon{
            width: 25px;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: none ;
           }

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
        .menu-icon{
            display: block;
        }
    
        #menuList{
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I went through the code and find out that togglemenu function is working properly and its even opening the menu. But you have given position absolute to ul tag and when you click on toggle image. It opens menu but at the top of page.

So click on image and scroll up to top and you will going to see your menu. You just have to adjust its position to open it below toggle menu button/image.

Comment: Thank you. Changed absolute to relative and it works fine. Though it looks a little messy, I'm satisfied with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting `max-height` and `max-width`

Changing those properties doesn’t change the size of the element, only what its max bounds are.

Use `width` and `height` instead.

Comment: I just tried using height instead. It seemed to have taken out all the codes after the line '@media only screen and (width: 700px)'. It is my understanding that (max-width:700px) is a condition which specifies that the following codes be activated if screen > 700px. I'm not sure what you mean by 'Changing those properties doesn’t change the size of the element'. If you could explain further, it'd be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: My apologies. The max width in the media query is fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's appear at the top of the page because of `position: absolute`

Comment: Thank you. Changed absolute to relative and it works fine. Though it looks a little messy, I'm satisfied with it. Thank you!